# adb pull - default path has been changed

Tags: adb, pull

When I try to pull a file using `adb pull <file>`, it used to be automatically saved in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot`.
Now, whenever I use the same command, it's saved in `C:\Users\khibr\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot`. I can't remember if I did anything to change the path, but I want to change it back. is There any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the following syntax to change where you want the file to be stored after the pull command.

```
adb pull file.txt C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot
```

Another way to do this is to open the command prompt from the directory where you want to pull the files to.

Comment: I know that command, but I wanted to know if there is any way to change the default path as I explained.

Comment: You can change the default directory by following the steps here:  https://techsupportwhale.com/change-default-directory-in-command-prompt/